# Block proxy when trying to connect one Nexus repo to another nexus repo

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

Bacially I'm trying to connect one repo nexus to another nexus repo. It shouldn't be much different than connecting a remote proxy to nexus. I just dont understand why nexus blocks this proxy? Anyone recognize the situation? Can one nexus repo not connect to another one. Perhaps the url is not right? (I'm using public url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this should simply work. The setup does not differ compared to connecting to the JBoss maven repository (they use nexus too). I think even maven central is based on nexus.

Do the logs tell you anything (or the system feeds in nexus) why the connection was blocked?

Usually this is authentication related or the server cannot resolve the url (seen that a couple of times in intranets where server have no DNS resolution)

Comment: that last sentence.. DNS resolution might be the key, I'm going to try with ip and see if that helps..

Comment: no it refuses to connect to other repo. "Attempting to Proxy and Remote Unavailable"

Comment: in the log I see that it says "Will not index hidden file path: contract_repository:/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties.md5

Comment: I can browse the files with the public url .. but still above message makes no sense

Comment: if you turn on debug logging in the administration section? does that give another hint?
does the jre/jdk have some special proxy settings in its environment variables? a weird issue. the error you posted looks like a path is not configured correctly.

Comment: it turned out to be dns problem of some sort as I had to add the full domain name of the other nexus public repo I was connecting to (never needed before). Its strange the IP did not work. Anyhow I'm going to except your answer and hopefully this helps someone.